# Need help in converting this simple for loop into another function that's being called recursively

Tags: c, recursion

How to integrate the for loop with the existing function or write a new function that runs from 0 to n where n is the input from user?

```
//Write a program in C or C++ to Print Fibonacci Series using recursion.
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", fib(i))
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My try:

```
//Write a program in C or C++ to Print Fibonacci Series using recursion.
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
void rec(int n)
{
    if(n>0)
        rec(n-1);
    else
        printf("%d", fib(n));
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    // for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    // {
    //     printf("%d", fib(i))
    // }
    rec(n);
    return 0;
}
```

This took my input correctly but output was 0.

I know I can print the Fibonacci series in a single function using static int or global variables but I am not allowed to use them. So is there any other way to print the Fibonacci series using recursion in a single function? If not, that's fine, 2 different recursive functions also works.

The code to print fibonacci series using recursion and static int variables is:

```
void fib(int n)
{
    static int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3;
    if (n > 0)
    {
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        printf("%d ", n3);
        fib(n - 1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    printf("0 1 ");
    fib(n - 2);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: Figured out the correct answer, thanks for replies. The code for this task is:

```
//Write a program in C to Print Fibonacci Series using recursion.
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
void rec(int n)
{
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        rec(n - 1);
        printf("%d ", fib(n));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    // for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    // {
    //     printf("%d ", fib(i));
    // }
    rec(n-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a typo: `int res(int);` -> `void rec(int);`? `rec()` is defined _after_ `main()` and not declared before. Hence, it's unknown when called in `main()`.

Comment: After the edit, it's still wrong: `int rec(int);` vs. `void rec(int) { }`.

Comment: Yes @Scheff'sCat , I made a typo and corrected it but it still doesnt give me correct output (no warnings though). I need a code in C or C++ to do the given task. I know C++ at a much higher level than C so it wouldn't be very hard for me to convert the C++ code to C, unless it's written in C++17 or C++20 (I included tags only for c++11, c++14

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I updated it, still the same issue..

Comment: We don't care what language you "need" the code in. We only care about what language the code in the question is written in. I'm deleting the C++ tags.

Comment: Ok, you can remove them but I hope you know that C code will run on C++ compilers too. So, technically this code is written in C++ as well as C

Comment: That's simply not true. C++ and C have been quite different languages for the last 22 years at least. Forget about misconceptions that C++ is some "super set" of C. That was only true back in the pre-standard days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've almost done. Use this recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>
   int rec(int n, int a = 0, int b = 1){
     if (n == 0)
        return a;
     if (n == 1)
        return b;
     return rec(n - 1, b, a + b);
   }
   
   int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", rec(i));
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: 6.c:20:26: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token

   20 |     int rec(int n, int a = 0, int b = 1){

      |                          ^

6.c: In function 'main':
It gives this error: 
6.c:38:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rec' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

   38 |         rec(n);

Comment: attached the full code. try and see whether still you get the error

Comment: 7.c:3:25: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token
    3 |    int rec(int n, int a = 0, int b = 1){
      |                         ^
7.c: In function 'main':
7.c:18:22: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rec' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   18 |         printf("%d", rec(i));
      |                      ^~~

Comment: hey it worked for me. Just try copy and pasting the above. And provide a valid integer as the input to the command line

Comment: Idk why but it doesn;t work for me and shows the given warnings and errors on VSCode. However, I see that you are using a for loop in main function. I have already written a code that uses for loop in main function and does the recursion correctly at the top of my question description. I need a recursive function as a replacement for the loop that calls another function with the argument being incremented by 1 in every call till the given limit...

Comment: This is actually C++ code disguised as C. And this is exactly why we need the OP to specify what language they are using before running off to write answers. Now they are likely compiling this on a C compiler and getting very strange results.